# OpenWeather API React Request Header Fields Too Large 431

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have been trying to use the following code using React `fetch` to get a response from the OpenWeather API:

```
    fetch('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Milwaukee&APPID=1234567890')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
       console.log(data)
```

When I skip react and just copy the url (`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Milwaukee&APPID=1234567890`) into the browser I get a totally valid response.  (For [example](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Seattle&APPID=3ad00fc7fad5156c45cba9a42b45c152) )  When I use the fetch code in my React application, however, I get the following error:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Milwaukee&APPID=1234567890
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 431 Request Header Fields Too Large
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I am running my react application off localhost from create-react-app.  Why can I access that API just fine from my browser but get an error in my app?

---

**Extra Information**

In case it is useful [here](https://openweathermap.org/appid) is the link to sign up for a free OpenWeather API

Here is the rest of the information from the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 431 Request Header Fields Too Large
x-powered-by: Express
connection: close
date: Wed, 18 Sep 2019 15:45:21 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

Or from the request header:

```
GET /api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Milwaukee&APPID=1234567890 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-US;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,ar-JO;q=0.6,ar;q=0.5
```

(My APPID is fake in all these examples, so the request won't work by just copying and pasting what I have)

Comment: What are you sending in your "headers"?

Comment: I guess I'm not totally sure.  I am either using the fetch above (1st code block) or just copying the URL.  My best guess at to what I'm sending for request headers is what I have copied in that last code block above.  I got that from the developer console under Network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty "catchy" bug - you are missing `http://` in front of your url, so:

```
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Milwaukee&APPID=1234567890')
```

Since you've missed it, url is resolved to this (you can see it in your Network tab):

```
http://localhost:3000/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Milwaukee&APPID=1234567890
```